# How do I keep the original font color after hover?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Hello guys I'm trying to keep the white color in this hover but I wasn't able to do it?,when I move the cursor to the next element inside the element with the hover the font change it's color, I been doing many different ways to try to keep the color I want but it seems nothing works,  some help please.
I show what's happening in this pics, I would appreciate some help.
https://ibb.co/nDLQ7w
https://ibb.co/j5NBfG
Sorry for my english I'm from japan.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Spectral+SC');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
html {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 32px;
  background-color: #212121;
  color: #555;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-family: 'Spectral sc', sans-serif;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 70px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 34px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
p {text-align: center;}
nav {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}
nav:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
nav ul {
  float: right;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
nav ul li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.icon {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
}
.toggle, [id^=drop] {display: none;}
nav ul li ul li:hover {background-color: #000;}
nav a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;}
nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {display: inherit;}
nav ul ul li {
  width: 170px;
  float: none;
  display: list-item;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul ul ul li {
  position: relative;
}

.logo {
  height: 70px;
  width: auto;
  margin: 5px 15px;
  float: left;
}
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.toggle-nav {display: none;}
.change .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {opacity: 0;}

.change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}
@media all and (max-width : 767px) {
  nav {margin: 0;}
  nav ul{float: left;clear:both;}
  .toggle + a, .menu {display: none;}
  .toggle {
    display: block;
    background-color: #254441;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
  }
  .toggle-nav {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .toggle:hover {background-color: #000;}
  [id^=drop]:checked + ul {display: block;}
  .logo {
   left: 50%;
   position: relative;
   transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav ul {
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav ul ul .toggle,
  nav ul ul a {padding: 0 40px;}
  nav ul ul ul a {padding: 0 80px;}

  nav a:hover,
  nav ul ul ul a {background-color: #000;}
  nav ul li ul li .toggle,
  nav ul ul a {background-color: #212121;}

  nav ul ul {
    float: none;
    position: static;
    color: #fff;
  }
  nav ul ul li:hover > ul,
  nav ul li:hover > ul {display: none;}

  nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav ul ul ul li {position: static;}
}
@media all and (max-width : 330px) {
  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 94%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/queries.css">
 <title>Web title</title>
</head>
<body>
 <nav>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png" class="logo">
  <label for="drop" class="toggle-nav" style="float: right;"><div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
</div></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="drop">
  <ul class="menu">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li>
    <label for="drop-1" class="toggle"">Services +</label>
    <a href="#">Services +</a>
    <input type="checkbox" id="drop-1">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Service 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Service 3</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
    <label for="drop-2" class="toggle"">Portfolio +</label>
    <a href="#">Portfolio +</a>
    <input type="checkbox" id="drop-2">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Service 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Service 3</a></li>
     <li>
      <label for="drop-3" class="toggle"">Port +</label>
      <a href="#">Port+</a>
      <input type="checkbox" id="drop-3">
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Service 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Service 3</a></li> 
      </ul>    
     </li>
    </ul>    
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
   
  </ul>
 </nav>
</body>

<script>
function myFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle("change");
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I ran your code with the js snippet you pasted but I can't replicate the issue.

Comment: when i move the cursor inside the element of port+ inside portfolio the text port+ doesn't keep the color white, but anyway thanks for try my friend  :)

Comment: I run snippet, it keeps `Port+` white. Seems it is alright.

Comment: it's very strange to me it keeps giving me the error, this a screenshot of what I'm watching... https://ibb.co/dgaBEb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider adding the `:hover` *pseudo-state* to the *containing* list-item (`li`) rather than the anchor element (`a`) itself, and use a **child combinator** (`>`)<sup>[Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)</sup> selector to target the directly nested anchor element (so that not all anchor elements nested within a given list item are affected), e.g:

```
nav li:hover > a {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

This way, when the cursor leaves the anchor element of a list item, which has a nested dropdown menu, the rules declared will still apply since the cursor is *still* hovering over the containing list item.

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

*Expand "Full page"*

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Spectral+SC');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
html {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 32px;
  background-color: #212121;
  color: #555;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-family: 'Spectral sc', sans-serif;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 70px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 34px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
p {text-align: center;}
nav {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}
nav:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
nav ul {
  float: right;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
nav ul li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.icon {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
}
.toggle, [id^=drop] {display: none;}
nav ul li ul li:hover {background-color: #000;}

/* Modified */
nav li:hover > a {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}


nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {display: inherit;}
nav ul ul li {
  width: 170px;
  float: none;
  display: list-item;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul ul ul li {
  position: relative;
}

.logo {
  height: 70px;
  width: auto;
  margin: 5px 15px;
  float: left;
}
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.toggle-nav {display: none;}
.change .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {opacity: 0;}

.change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}
@media all and (max-width : 767px) {
  nav {margin: 0;}
  nav ul{float: left;clear:both;}
  .toggle + a, .menu {display: none;}
  .toggle {
    display: block;
    background-color: #254441;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
  }
  .toggle-nav {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .toggle:hover {background-color: #000;}
  [id^=drop]:checked + ul {display: block;}
  .logo {
   left: 50%;
   position: relative;
   transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav ul {
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav ul ul .toggle,
  nav ul ul a {padding: 0 40px;}
  nav ul ul ul a {padding: 0 80px;}

  nav a:hover,
  nav ul ul ul a {background-color: #000;}
  nav ul li ul li .toggle,
  nav ul ul a {background-color: #212121;}

  nav ul ul {
    float: none;
    position: static;
    color: #fff;
  }
  nav ul ul li:hover > ul,
  nav ul li:hover > ul {display: none;}

  nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav ul ul ul li {position: static;}
}
@media all and (max-width : 330px) {
  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 94%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/queries.css">
 <title>Web title</title>
</head>
<body>
 <nav>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png" class="logo">
  <label for="drop" class="toggle-nav" style="float: right;"><div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
</div></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="drop">
  <ul class="menu">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li>
    <label for="drop-1" class="toggle">Services +</label>
    <a href="#">Services +</a>
    <input type="checkbox" id="drop-1">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Service 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Service 3</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
    <label for="drop-2" class="toggle">Portfolio +</label>
    <a href="#">Portfolio +</a>
    <input type="checkbox" id="drop-2">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Service 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Service 3</a></li>
     <li>
      <label for="drop-3" class="toggle">Port +</label>
      <a href="#">Port+</a>
      <input type="checkbox" id="drop-3">
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Service 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Service 3</a></li> 
      </ul>    
     </li>
    </ul>    
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
   
  </ul>
 </nav>
</body>

<script>
function myFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle("change");
}
</script>
</html>
```

*Note: check your markup on `label` elements as well, where class `.toggle` is terminated with double closing apostrophes.*

Comment: thank you so much awesome and useful answer, it works completely fine
thanks

Comment: @numero1 Happy to help, and glad you found this answer not only awesome but useful as well :)

Answer (score 0):

add this css, may be this will help you

```css
 ul li a, ul li a:hover, ul li a:active{
  color:#fff !important;
 }
```

Comment: can i have live link where you are facing the issue?

Comment: else add your absolute paths for css and js, so that we clearly look into

Answer (score 0):

nav ul ul li a:hover{background-color: #fff; color: #ccc;}